# How many elements of order $n$ exist in $\mathbb{Z}/(n,p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, with $p$ prime number?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

> I'm wondering how many elements of order $n$ exist in $\mathbb{Z}/(n,p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, with $p$ prime number?

I know that: For each $d\mid n$, there are exactly $\varphi(d)$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of order $d$.

So in my case, if $n\mid (n,p-1)$ there are $\varphi (n)$ elements, otherwise if $n\not\mid(n,p-1)$ I don't know how many do exist?

Comment: By $(n,p-1)$ do you mean $gcd(n, p-1)$?

Comment: @freakish yes sorry

Comment: @freakish Oh my god, it's quite obvious of course, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ doesn't divide the order of the group, in this case $(n,p-1)$, then there is no element of order $n$ in the group by Lagrange's theorem.